# Are 'treasures' all Earthly goods or wealth?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-translation, exegesis

When it is often repeated in the Bible that we must cast aside our treasures to gain an everlasting treasure in Heaven, does this mean ALL worldly possessions or just money? Do modern desirables (ipods, Playstations, cars, gadgets, incredibly detailed statues, watches etc.etc.etc.) count? I assume they do, just checking...

Comment: To which passage(s) are you referring? (e.g. "cast aside ... treasures")

Answer (score 2):

If I read these Scriptures correctly What Jesus considers treasure to be is the things you value the most.

Matthew 12:35  KJV

> A good man out of the good treasure of the heart bringeth forth good things: and an evil man out of the evil treasure bringeth forth evil things.

Matthew 6:21  KJV

> For where your treasure is, there will your heart be also.

For Satan as for many people today their treasure is power and or authority:

Luke 4:6  KJV

> And the devil said unto him, All this power will I give thee, and the glory of them: for that is delivered unto me; and to whomsoever I will I give it.

How Man treasures power is portrayed in the exchange between Pilate and Jesus:

John 19:10 and 11  KJV

> 10 Then saith Pilate unto him, Speakest thou not unto me? knowest thou not that I have power to crucify thee, and have power to release thee?
>
> 11  Jesus answered, Thou couldest have no power at all against me, except it were given thee from above: therefore he that delivered me unto thee hath the greater sin.
> Even today look at politics and how so many are willing to risk their monetary fortunes to gain a position in Government, and the amount of money some contributors are willing to donate in hopes of gaining political influence.

In answer to your question in my feeble mind as far as the Kingdom goes it probably  has to do with whatever it is that you desire more than obedience to God.